# Using a comma separated string of IDs vs. a multivalued field

Tags: solr

In my project, I have come to terms with creating relations between documents by storing them in a comma separated field, e.g.: `relatedDocIds="2455,4564,7345"` Those relations are updated from time to time by using a scheduled job that run through my DB, fetches a record, and updates its Solr document.

I know that instead of using a single comma-separated string field, I can use a `multiValued` string, where each ID could take one value slot. due to some limitations of my client API though, I can only set one value per field at the moment. I have not seen any disadvantages to using it the way I do, i.e. queries, such as `relatedDocIds:2455` resolve exactly the way I want them to. The documentation of `multiValued` says that it does the same thing.

Am I missing a potential advantage of using `multiValued`? Is my method OK, and what are its limits? What would be a better and more optimized approach to store those IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine. Under the covers, the indexed form of the multiValued field is converted to a set of tokens, the same as if your tokenizer split them using that particular tokenizer's rule.

The main difference is that multiValued field pretends that the end token of one value and start token of another value are far from each other. That's what the *positionIncrementGap* means (usually 100).

This matters if you wanted to do a phrase search like "2455,4564". In your case, I believe, it will match, but if you had them as multiValued field with each value separate, it would not.

And, of course, multiValued fields - if stored - are returned as an array of value. Strings - if stored - are returned as they were given, even if the indexed version has all been broken up into the tokens.